# Xamarin UWP app won't install for multiple users

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have created a Xamarin UWP app and installed it on a company PC, all seems fine. Multiple people log on to these PC's however and it seems that only the person who installed the app can access it. I can't seem to find it on any other user account.

When I try to install it via a different user account I get a 'Catastrophic Failure (0x8000ffff)' error from the appinstaller.

Pretty stumped about this as we need multiple users to be able to access the app on the PC, either using the same installation or an installation per account.

Comment: Probably asking in the wrong place, sounds like a question for https://superuser.com

Comment: @dubdub cheers, yeah I've never actually used any of the Q&A sites so I just assumed and threw it on here but I'll keep in mind for next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay just in case anyone stumbles across this,

I needed to run the supplied install PowerShell script, instead of the appinstaller.